# AJAX call on form date validation from MySQL wont work again until page refresh

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I'm new to AJAX but was able to get some form validation checking for existing values in a MySQL database. Everything works fine except my AJAX date validation. It only validates properly once. If I refresh the page it validates correctly again. I assigned the new Date().getTime() to the url because I thought it might be a cache issue but I still have the same results. I'm using the same type of validation for a number and an email on the same form and they work every time without refreshing the page. Here's my [test form](http://ericrohloff.com/coffeecup/ccforum/formbuilder/form_validation_mysql/mysqlvalidation/mysqlvalidation/mysqlvalidation3.html). Existing dates in the database are Oct 14, 15, 16 and 17 2013. The date format in the database is 0000-00-00 or 2013-10-14 Existing numbers 1, 2, 3, and 4. Existing email is you@me.com and me@you.com.
I don't want the form to vaidate if the values exist in the database. 
Here's my JS code.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$('#fb-submit-button').attr('disabled','disabled');
var emailok = false;
var numberok = false;
var boxes = $(".fb-item");
var myForm = $("#docContainer"), 
number = $("#item3_number_1"), 
 email = $("#item4_email_1"), 
 numberInfo = $("#numberInfo"), 
 emailInfo = $("#emailInfo");


   //send ajax request to check email

email.blur(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "email="+$(this).attr("value"),
        url: "../../formcheck_email.php",
        beforeSend: function(){
            emailInfo.html("<font color='blue'>Checking Email...</font>");
        },
        success: function(data){
            if(data == "invalid")
            {
                emailok = false;
                emailInfo.html("<font color='red'>Invalid Email</font>");
            $('#fb-submit-button').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
            else if(data != "0")
            {
                emailok = false;
                emailInfo.html("<font color='red'>Email Already Exist</font>");            
               $('#fb-submit-button').attr('disabled','disabled');

            }
            else
            {
                emailok = true;
                emailInfo.html("<font color='green'>Email OK</font>");
               $('#fb-submit-button').attr('disabled','');
            }
        }
      });
   });  




    //send ajax request to check number

number.blur(function(){
    $.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        data: "number="+$(this).attr("value"),
        url: "../../formcheck_number.php",
        beforeSend: function(){
            numberInfo.html("<font color='blue'>Checking Number...</font>");
        },
        success: function(data){

             if(data != "0")
            {

                numberok = false;
                numberInfo.html("<font color='red'>Number Already Exist</font>");
               $('#fb-submit-button').attr('disabled','disabled');
            }
            else
            {
                numberok = true;
                numberInfo.html("<font color='green'>Number OK</font>");
               $('#fb-submit-button').attr('disabled','');
            }
        }
       });

    });

    //send ajax request to check date


$('#fb-submit-button').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
       $('.datepicker').datepicker({
      onSelect: function(dateText) {
  $("#item61_date_1").datepicker();    
        post_date = $('.datepicker'),
        dateInfo = $('#dateInfo');

    //send ajax request to check date            

        dateInfo.html('<font color="blue">Checking Date...</font>');
           $.ajax({
                url: '../../formcheck_date.php',
                data: {post_date: $(this).val()},
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data) {
                    dateok = (data == '0');
                    dateInfo.html('<font color="' + (dateok ? 'green' : 'red') + '">Date ' +
                          (dateok ? 'Available' : 'Already Taken') + '</font>');
                    $('#fb-submit-button').attr('disabled', dateok ? '' : 'disabled');
                }
           });

     }
  });

   });
```

Here's my php database hook up.

```
    <?php
    require_once('pdo_connect.php');
    $post_date = $_POST['post_date'];
    $sql= "SELECT post_date FROM validation where post_date='$post_date'";
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $msg = $stmt->rowCount();


    if($msg !== false) {

    echo $msg;
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Upon further research I finally figured out that it was the datepicker that was the actual problem. I change the id of the selector and included the datepicker library and it now works. It was the built in scripts that were generated by that app that was blocking the posting of the date on the first click. I updated the code to reflect the updated version.

Answer (score 0):

Default mysql date format is `'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'` I think you are directly passing the input value of date to the query without changing the format.
you can do it by using

`date('Y-m-d',strtotime('10/16/2013'));`

or directly use (for date format like Oct 16)

```
select count(*) as datecount 
from your_table  
where date_field = DATE_FORMAT($POST_DATE,"%M %e");
```

**you cannot use reserved keyword date like that use backticks to escape**

There is also two other problems mysql_* is deprecated also sql injection

proper way to get the value of datepicker is `$('#datepick_id').datepicker('getDate');`

Comment: That's what I thought also but my date in my mysql is only a date 0000-00-00. I see your date in the actual mysql admin panel as 2013-10-17.

Comment: I think you were on the right track. I think the formatting of the date is the issue. 2013-10-17 vs 2013/10/17 is a problem.

Comment: I updated to pdo as I should have done in the first place. Thanks for that reminder.;) I'm still not getting good validation with the date. I changed the variable so the date is now $post_date = $_POST['post_date'] and the database field is post_date. I tried the date format but still not getting the correct validation. What happens now is if you select a date it will show unavailable then if you select it again it shows available. Very strange. Not sure where the hiccup is at. I updated the posted code to reflect my changes.

Comment: I've now determined that it's the datepicker creating the problem. If I hand type the dates in it validates the date values in the database every time. I'll dig into the datepicker to see what's causing the issue. Anybody have any ideas? Thanks.